# Why, using "and" in a for loop and "or" in a while loop gives the same result?

Tags: python, logic, demorgans-law

I am trying to practice writing these loops, and I had an exercise which asked me to print numbers from *0* to *20* that **aren't** divisible by *3* or *5*.
For the `while` loop, I wrote this code:

```
#solution with while

i = 0

while i < 21:
    i += 1
    if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0:
        continue
    print(i)
```

Whereas, for the `for...in` loop, I struggled because I found out that I needed to use `and` instead of `or` here.
The code is as follows:

```
#solution with for

for k in range(21):
    if k % 3 != 0 and k % 5 != 0:
        print(k)
```

Why did I have to change the logical operator?

In my head, the first rows of the two codes do the same thing, iterate a number from *0* to *20*. So the condition, after these, should be equal for both the iterations used.
Can anyone explain to me what am I missing here?

Comment: You can use the same `if ... continue` logic in a `for` loop.

Comment: Note that the `while` loop uses `== 0` while the `for` loop uses `!= 0`. That is, the sense of the test is reversed. This requires the conjunction be changed. See [DeMorgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

Comment: In the while you DON'T print, in the for you DO print, so the condition are opposite, see https://brilliant.org/wiki/de-morgans-laws/ : change the or/and and change the ==/!=

Comment: If you have an exactly equivalent for loop it will also work, e.g. `for k in range(1, 21): if k % 3 == 0 or k % 5 == 0: continue; print(k)`

Comment: There is a problem within your solution with while. `i = 0 while i < 21: i += 1 ` here, you are doing an increment before the logic execution, so you indeed iterate the number from 1 to 21 instead of 0 to 20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a loop type problem, the issue is in using different equality operators in your conditions - `!=` instead of `==`.

After changing `or` to `and`, the result stays the same because you've accidentally used *[De Morgan's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) second law* (*negation of disjunction*):
[image: De Morgan's 2nd law]

---

Now, let's look at the code.

In the `while` loop:

- the program doesn't print `i`:

  - if it's divisible by *3* (but not necessarily by *5*)
    **or**
  - if it's divisible by *5* (but not necessarily by *3*).

In other words:

- the program prints `i`:

  - if it's not divisible by *3*
    **and**
  - if it's not divisible by *5*.

---

Noe, let's check, what says the condition in the `for...in` loop:

- the program prints `k`:

  - if it's not divisible by *3*
    **and**
  - if it's not divisible by *5*.

Looks like the same condition, doesn't it?
As you noticed, in the *In other words:* paragraph, we've naturally used the *negation of disjunction*.

To sum up, both programs for `i` / `k` lower than *21* print:

```
0
1
2
4
7
8
11
13
14
16
17
19
```

---

If you still aren't sure, try to replace the conditions between loops:

```py
i = 0
while i < 21:
    i += 1
    if i % 3 != 0 and i % 5 != 0:
        print(i)
```

```py
for k in range(21):
    if k % 3 == 0 or k % 5 == 0:
        continue
    print(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

The two loop types are totally equivalent. You had to use `and` instead of `or`, and `!=` instead of `==`, because you reversed the logic.

In the first case, you are saying *"if the number is divisible then skip it, else print it"* while in the second one_ "if the number is not divisible then print (else do nothing)"_.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have also changed the conditions for the results in the while loop you have used ==, but in for loop you have used != if you modify the code you will get the same output by or operator in both

```
for k in range(21):
    if k % 3 == 0 or k % 5 == 0:
        continue
    print(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

In while loop.

```
if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0: # this means when i is evenly divided by 3 or 5 then don't do anything. 
        continue
    print(i) # means only print i when i is not evenly divided by 3 and 5
```

And in the for loop

```
if k % 3 != 0 and k % 5 != 0: # here this means print i when k is not evenly divided by 3 and 5. Which same as while loop
        print(k)
```

---

You just reverse order and nothing. You can use the same method in both way and you will get the same result.

While loop

```
i = 0
while i < 21:
    i += 1
    if i % 3 != 0 and i % 5 != 0:
        print(i)
```

For Loop

```
for a in range(21):
    if a % 3 != 0 and a % 5 != 0:
        print(a)
```